# Is there any way to call an endpoint after every 5 minutes with app in background

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to call an endpoint after every 5 minutes and it's working fine with `Timer` when app is active but when app goes to background the `Timer` stops firing because timers don't work in background. Is there any possible way to achieve this even with the use of private api because i am not planning to upload the app on AppStore.

Comment: No, you generally would not have it fire every 5 minutes. If you’re trying to post location updates, you can use background location service to get updates when there is a material location update. If you’re trying to fetch server updates, you can use background fetch, but that’s triggered at the discretion of the OS (based upon historical patterns), not at some fixed interval, and certainly not every 5 minutes. If you need to have your server notify the app of data updates, consider push notifications. If you tell us why you want to poll every five minutes, we can advise you how to proceed.

Comment: That having been said, if you’re not distributing it via the App Store, you can keep the app running in the background, but recognize that this five minute timer pattern will crush the user’s battery, so I’d advise against that unless your use case assumes the user will keep their device attached to power and you don’t mind eating into their data plan.

Comment: I need to inform the server that the application is still active

Comment: it's actually payment processing application and need to process the payments, so i need to let server know that the application is online to receive payment requests.

Comment: I’d suggest you consider push notification pattern. The user will be proactively notified of the payment request, without the battery and data plan implications of polling every 5 minutes.

Comment: We are already using the push notifications. Sometime clients expectations goes beyond the limitations :). But anyway thanks for your time and suggestion

Comment: I would expect that push notifications would deliver significantly lower latency than 5 minutes; delivery is almost instantaneous. You can use a combination approach. If your app is in the foreground then maintain a web socket connection (or similar). If it is in the background use push notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no. Apple goes to significant lengths to prevent apps from doing this sort of thing since it is a significant battery drain.

You might look at using the `BGTaskScheduler` API to schedule background requests that you would like the system to perform on your behalf, but you won't get a frequency anywhere near every 5 minutes.